# Babel errors when files to transpile not in certain location

Tags: browserify, babeljs

I copied the js files from project https://github.com/videojs/video.js into a subfolder of my project.
I set up plenty dependencies and called `browserify` on the command line:

`node ./node_modules/browserify/bin/cmd.js dev\videojs\js\video.js -t [ babelify ]`

The output looks like:

```
Error: D:/Webs/videojs/dev/videojs/js/video.js: Cannot find module '../../package.json' from 'D:\Webs\videojs\dev\videojs\js'
    at Function.module.exports [as sync] (D:\Webs\videojs\node_modules\resolve\lib\sync.js:33:11)
    at PluginPass.MemberExpression (D:\Webs\videojs\node_modules\babel-plugin-inline-json\lib\index.js:27:45)
    at newFn (D:\Webs\videojs\node_modules\babel-traverse\lib\visitors.js:276:21)
    at NodePath._call (D:\Webs\videojs\node_modules\babel-traverse\lib\path\context.js:76:18)
    at NodePath.call (D:\Webs\videojs\node_modules\babel-traverse\lib\path\context.js:48:17)
    at NodePath.visit (D:\Webs\videojs\node_modules\babel-traverse\lib\path\context.js:105:12)
    at TraversalContext.visitQueue (D:\Webs\videojs\node_modules\babel-traverse\lib\context.js:150:16)
    at TraversalContext.visitSingle (D:\Webs\videojs\node_modules\babel-traverse\lib\context.js:108:19)
    at TraversalContext.visit (D:\Webs\videojs\node_modules\babel-traverse\lib\context.js:192:19)
    at Function.traverse.node (D:\Webs\videojs\node_modules\babel-traverse\lib\index.js:114:17)
```

When I move the files one folder up, the command runs and and transpiles all the files.

I now wonder where this error comes from. `babel-traverse` seemingly loops through the plugins and eventually finds out it's being run not exactly 3 levels below the project root. Is this intended behaviour? It this a matter of babel, browserify, a plugin or videojs?

Answer (score 1):

Use this command instead:

```
./node_modules/.bin/browserify dev\videojs\js\video.js -t [ babelify ]
```

When Browserify is installed, the command line scripts are added to `node_modules/.bin`, as that's the standard practice. It's those commands that you should be running; not the scripts in Browserify's own `bin` directory.

Note that the scripts are either shell scripts or Windows CMD scripts and that they are not run using `node`.

Or, if you add the following to your `package.json`, you can run Browserify using NPM (also standard practice):

```
{

    ...
    "scripts": {
        "browserify": "browserify"
    }
}
```

and the command would then be:

```
npm run browserify dev\videojs\js\video.js -t [ babelify ]
```

Or, if you want to keep the parameters in the `"scripts"` configuration:

```
{

    ...
    "scripts": {
        "bundle": "browserify dev/videojs/js/video.js -t [ babelify ]"
    }
}
```

and:

```
npm run bundle
```

Comment: I was a bit premature with my praise. I moved the js folder around and eventually ended up with `Cannot find module '../../package.json'` message. Calling `node_modules\.bin\browserify` and putting this into the `scripts` hierarchy in the package.json is a valuable tip, though.

Comment: I've re-read your question. Is there a reason you've chosen not to install video.js [using NPM](http://videojs.com/getting-started/#download-npm)? I would do that, rather than put it in a "subfolder of my project".